# Como usar variaveis dinamicamente no vue

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Gostaria de saber como utilizar a `propriedade` de um `Objeto` para no componente concatenar com string e se tornar o nome da classe no `v-for`

Meu objeto:

```
data(){
    return{
        user: {name:""}
    }
}
```

gostaria que na minha classe tivesse o nome `pencilName`

```
<div v-for="(value, propertyName) in user">
     <div class="'pencil'+propertyName[0].toUpperCase() + propertyName.slice(1)" >
         <strong>{{propertyName}}</strong>
     </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria que o resultado fosse esse:

```
<div>
     <div class="pencilName" >
         <strong>Name</strong>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para atingir exatamente o resultado que você deseja, mediante ao código, faltou apenas você colocar o `:class` ou `v-bind:class` que funcionará. Segue abaixo:

```
<div v-for="(value, propertyName) in user">
    <div :class="'pencil'+propertyName[0].toUpperCase() +  propertyName.slice(1)" >
        <strong>{{propertyName}}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Verdade, acredita que esqueci disso, vlw